Azure Speech SDK Pronunciation Assessment Always Returns AccuracyScore = 0
I'm trying to add pronunciation assessment to my code using Azure's Speech SDK. Here’s the code I’m using:
            public static AudioConfig CreateAudioConfigFromBytes(byte[] audioBytes)
        {
            var audioStream = new MemoryStream(audioBytes);

            var pushStream = AudioInputStream.CreatePushStream();

            pushStream.Write(audioBytes);
            pushStream.Close();

            var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(pushStream);
            return audioConfig;
        }


public async Task<float> AssessPronunciation(byte[] audioBytes, string referenceText)
{
    string subscriptionKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("STT_API_KEY");

    var pronunciationAssessmentConfig = new PronunciationAssessmentConfig(
        referenceText: referenceText,
        gradingSystem: GradingSystem.HundredMark,
        granularity: Granularity.Phoneme,
        enableMiscue: false);

    var audioConfig = CreateAudioConfigFromBytes(audioBytes);
    var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, "eastus");

    using (var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig))
    {
        pronunciationAssessmentConfig.ApplyTo(speechRecognizer);
        var speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();

        // The pronunciation assessment result as a Speech SDK object
        var pronunciationAssessmentResult = PronunciationAssessmentResult.FromResult(speechRecognitionResult);

        // The pronunciation assessment result as a JSON string
        var pronunciationAssessmentResultJson = speechRecognitionResult.Properties.GetProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceResponse_JsonResult);
    }
}

When I test this on different words, I consistently get AccuracyScore = 0, regardless of the pronunciation.
As a comparison, I tried assessing the word "school" and pronounced it correctly once and incorrectly (saying "pajama") another time. In both cases, I still received an AccuracyScore of 0 from this code.
To ensure the issue wasn't due to my pronunciation, I tested this directly through the Azure portal:
When I pronounced "school" correctly, I got a score above 90.
When I said "pajama" instead, I received a score of 2.
This shows that the pronunciation assessment works as expected in the portal but somehow doesn't work from my code.
Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong, or how I could fix this?

I can see the AccuracyScore in the output.

Is the issue got fixed?

Here is my GitHub repository, with complete code, try it.

Have you tried the code which I shared in the above comment?

I opened a new project and I tried your code exactly as is, (I just changed the key and the wav file path) and I am still getting always 0 for accuracy.
To make sure the file is ok I loaded it here:
https://speech.microsoft.com/portal/pronunciationassessmenttool
and for the text school I got accuracy 100.
Any other idea what can cause the same code to give me ifferent result?

Can you share the text in your .wav file?

The issue is with the .wav audio file only. Try to create a new file with the correct audio data in it and use that in the code.

The wav is a recording of the word 'school', how do you want me to share it?

I have an idea how we can try on same files.
I found this website that create a wav from text.
https://www.narakeet.com/app/text-to-audio
I put the word 'school' and created a wav file, running it on your code returned accuracy 0.  I tried it on some other words from this website and for all of the accuracy 0.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For Premature Stream Closure :
Do not close the pushStream until after the recognition task is completed. Also, ensure that you write to the pushStream after starting the recognition task.
For Missing Language Parameter:
Specify the language (e.g., "en-US") when creating the SpeechRecognizer instance
Ensure your audio bytes conform to the required format
public async Task<float> AssessPronunciation(byte[] audioBytes, string referenceText)
{
    string subscriptionKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("STT_API_KEY");

    var pronunciationAssessmentConfig = new PronunciationAssessmentConfig(
        referenceText: referenceText,
        gradingSystem: GradingSystem.HundredMark,
        granularity: Granularity.Phoneme,
        enableMiscue: false);

    var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, "eastus");

    // Specify the language
    string language = "en-US";
    speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = language;

    using (var pushStream = AudioInputStream.CreatePushStream())
    {
        var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(pushStream);

        using (var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, language, audioConfig))
        {
            pronunciationAssessmentConfig.ApplyTo(speechRecognizer);

            // Start recognition task
            var recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();

            // Write audio data to push stream after starting recognition
            pushStream.Write(audioBytes);
            pushStream.Close();

            // Wait for recognition to complete
            var speechRecognitionResult = await recognitionTask;

            // Check if recognition was successful
            if (speechRecognitionResult.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
            {
                var pronunciationAssessmentResult = PronunciationAssessmentResult.FromResult(speechRecognitionResult);
                var accuracyScore = pronunciationAssessmentResult.AccuracyScore;

                // Optionally, process the JSON result
                var pronunciationAssessmentResultJson = speechRecognitionResult.Properties.GetProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceResponse_JsonResult);

                return accuracyScore;
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle recognition failure
                throw new Exception($"Speech recognition failed with reason: {speechRecognitionResult.Reason}");
            }
        }
    }
}

Before using the audio bytes, confirm that they are in the correct format (PCM, 16-bit, 16 kHz, mono). If not, you'll need to convert them to this format and try using a known good audio file in the correct format to test the code. This can help determine if the issue is with the audio data or the code logic.

I copy pased your code and unfortunately I got the same accuracy 0 result  :-(
About the format, Ito make sure its good I sent it also to STT api and it worked so I guess it means that the format is ok
